update a column in supabase auth.users table after new user inserted in the table
I'm inserting new user in auth.users, then using data to populate the profiles table using function/trigger ...all ok
Once I do insert on auth.users I want use other function/trigger to update the phone column in the auth.users table.
here is the code :
                final email = _emailController.text; 
                final password = _passwordController.text;
                final mobile = phoneNumberProvider!.phoneNumber;

                 await supabaseClient.auth.signUp(
                  email: email,
                  password: password,
                  emailRedirectTo: 'io.supabase.app://login-callback/',
                  data: {
                    "user_mobile": mobile,
                    "user_is_admin": false,
                    "email": email
                  },
                  //captchaToken: '',
                  //channel: OtpChannel.whatsapp,
                )

Function and trigger as follows :
                 create or replace function public.add_mobile_number_on_signup()
                 returns trigger 
                 security definer set search_path = pg_catalog,pg_temp
                 as
                 $$
                 begin
                    update auth.users set new.raw_user_meta_data->> 'phone' where 
                    email = raw_user_meta_data->> 'email'  ;
                return new;
                end
                $$
                language plpgsql;


 
                create trigger on_auth_user_created_add_phone
                after insert on auth.users
                for each row execute function  public.add_mobile_number_on_signup();

Unfortunately the phone columns doesn't get updated.
Any help appriciated.
